# Using acf function in r for time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to `time-series analysis` and have a data set with a daily time step at 5 factor levels. My goal is to use the `acf` function in R to determine whether there is significant autocorrelation across the response variable of interest so that I can justify whether or not a time-series model is necessary.

I have sorted the dataset by Day, and am using the following code:

```
acf(DE_vec, lag.max=7)
```

The dataset has not been converted to a time-series object…it is a vector sorted by Day.

My first question is whether the dataframe should be converted to a time-series object, or if it is also correct to sort the vector by Day?

Second, if I have a variable repeated over the 5 levels for each Day, then should I construct 5 different `acf` plots for each level, or would it be ok to pool over stations as was done with the code above?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `acf` is for the analysis of object that are ts-objects. I do not see 'data.frame in the types of objects that `acf` is supposed to accept. Why don't you go back to your textbook and also do some worked examples in the help pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `acf()` will work on a `data.frame` class, and yes, you should compute the ACF for each of the 5 levels separately. If you pass the entire df to `acf()`, it will return the ACF for each of the levels.

If you are curious about the relationship across levels, then you need to use `ccf()` or some mutual information metric like those in the `entropy` or `infotheo` pkgs.